# Get array from php, and get its index in jquery using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wonder if I can access an array through jQuery by its index like this: `output_string['color'][1]`

I actually, build an array of elements like this (it works):

PHP

```
 $arreglo = array(
    'color' => $skin['Color'],
    'textu' => $skin['ImagenTextura'],
    'header' => $skin['Imagen'],
    'sombra' => $skin['ImagenSombra'],
    'tooltip' => $skin['TooltipColor']
 );

echo json_encode($arreglo);
```

And if I want to get to the file, I get the array like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: { 'dataString': result },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#loader").show();
            },
            success: function(output_string){ 
                            alert(output_string['color']);
                            }
      });
```

The problem is that, this time, more than one loop will be loaded, so I need to access it like this: `output_string['color'][1]`

Thanks

Comment: Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: If `$skin['Color']` is a non-associative array it will be encoded as a JSON array, and you'll be able to reference its items numerically. Are you getting any errors when you try to do it?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, would it work @JanTojnar ?

Comment: As @freejosh writes, but don't forget arrays are indexed from 0 in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#loader").show();
    },
    success: function(output_string) { 
        $.each(output_string, function (i, item) {
             alert(i + " " +item);
        });
    }
});
```

If your php is working correctly (as u said) you will get an alert for each result from there.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's ajax() returns an object when using the json dataType. This works for multi-dimensional objects too.

Can you be a little bit more specific on your question?